# How can I insert a number into MySQL and have it autoincrement that number for all rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to assign a company ID to  a group of contacts I have in a MySQL database; the contacts are already in the database, but they are missing the CID (company id) and there are 218 contacts.

I'm looking to do something along the lines of:

```
$cid = 549
increment $CID +1 x 218

insert into contacts (cid = $cid)
```

I know I'm way off, but hopefully you get the idea.

**edit**
seems alot of people are thinking i just need to autoincrement my CID row, which i already have. The problem is i am importing some customer data using a few excel spreadsheets, if i let auto increment do it, they wont match up.

In order for this to work I have to say "take 1st row and make the CID = 549, then the next row needs to be 550, next 551 and so forth.  they HAVE to be those numbers (549-767)

Comment: why dont you make a new column CID and make it auto_increment, it will automatically assign values

Comment: MySQL allows inserting and updating auto incrementing fields.

Comment: It seems you need to create a `companies` table and use an autoincrement field from there

Comment: Using columns like `CID` is going to make supporting this code infuriatingly hard. It's much better to use a name like `company_id` to represent these things as then there's no ambiguity.

Comment: @bnelsonjax: You have yet to give the rows IDs, so there should not be anything that cares about the exact numbers yet.  What makes it so important that the IDs be exactly 549-767, but makes the ID->row assignment so irrelevant that it was not part of the insert in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inserted damaged data that needs to be repaired, so you've got a number of ways of going about this. You could update it by hand, that'd work, but that could get messy if you make a mistake.

Another way is to create a look-up table for the missing identifiers by leveraging the MySQL auto-increment field.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _cid_fix(
  cid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  contact_id INT,
  INDEX idx_contact(contact_id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=549;
```

This creates a temporary table with the auto-increment primed at 549. Now insert into this the records with missing values:

```
INSERT INTO _cid_fix (contact_id) SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE cid IS NULL
```

Then you have a table of `contact_id` -> missing `CID`.

```
UPDATE contacts,_cid_fix SET contacts.cid=_cid_fix.id WHERE contacts.id=_cid_fix.contact_id
```

You can adjust the `WHERE` clause on the `INSERT` to match the records you require.

As `_cid_fix` is a `TEMPORARY` table, it will be destroyed when you close your connection to the MySQL server so there's no need to manually remove it. Note that other connections will not be able to see it, though, so if you're trying to inspect it using a different window or tool, it won't be there.